# SQL Server Monitoring Packages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, monitoring

I'm looking into purchasing a SQL Server monitoring system.

It should work with 2005/2008.

We would like to monitor performance, availability, backups, jobs and various database issues (space)

What has worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quest Software has a product called Spotlight.

Red Gate has a product called [SQL Response](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Response/index.htm).

I'm currently using both SQL Response and Quest Spotlight to monitor my SQL2000+ databases. They are both good: Spotlight saves playback data which is occasionally useful (don't forget about additional overhead) and their custom SSRS map pack is really good (ex. daily subscription for job failures report). What i like about SQL Response is it's ease of installation and configuration (especially email)... and the GUI feels really intuitive.

I have yet to try out Operations Manager/System Center Operations Manager to monitor my SQL boxes.

Comment: I used the beta of Response - I'll have to check it out again.  It seemed pretty useful, but sure did generate a large amount of reports.

Answer (score 1):

There are two flavours of monitoring tool for SQL Server. An alerting tool which lets you know when some attention is needed, and a passive monitoring tool that can be used for live diagnostics, trending analysis, historical graphs, etc.

- Spotlight is best at providing real time diagnostics and reports.
- MOM/SQL Response is better at alerts - and perhaps even look at hp OpenView. I also use Idera's SQL Compliance Manager for security alerts.

I haven't played with the Idera tool yet.

You could even create your own monitoring with SQL Agent and SQL Mail.

Comment: Thanks Mark,  We've got the home grown SSIS solution I've created, but it only runs a few times a day - looking to avoid sinking a bunch of time into writing and maintining, and most of all doubting my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've demoed a few of the Quest products:

http://www.quest.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I love Idera's DM product as well: [Idera DM](http://www.idera.com/Products/SQL-Server/SQL-diagnostic-manager/). There are a few good reviews on the web as well: [Review 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/afdc0683-f17c-489a-9dce-738e72ccdf46) and [Review 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic232217-202-1.aspx)